# how to set layout for a fragment?

Tags: android

it's a multi tap activity >>
I'm trying to set a layout for each tab but it doesnt work !
it simply shows nothing in both tabs !

Here's the code

```
 public class Game extends Activity { 

    public static Context appContext;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        //ActionBar gets initiated
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
       //Tell the ActionBar we want to use Tabs.
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
       //initiating both tabs and set text to it.
        ActionBar.Tab roundTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Round 55");
        ActionBar.Tab scoreTab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Score 55");

      //create the two fragments we want to use for display content
        Fragment roundFragment = new roundFragment();
        Fragment scoreFragment = new scoreFragment();

     //set the Tab listener. Now we can listen for clicks.
        roundTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(roundFragment));
        scoreTab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(scoreFragment));
      //add the two tabs to the actionbar
        actionbar.addTab(roundTab);
        actionbar.addTab(scoreTab);
    }



    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        public Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }


        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

    }

    public class roundFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.round, container, false);
        }

    }

    public class scoreFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.score, container, false);
        }

    }


 }
```

Comment: have you checked LogCat? I would also put some `Log.d` calls to check if the fragments' `onCreateView` is called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onTabSelected()` is empty. that's why it shows nothing on selection.

Add this code to your `onTabSelected()` of your `MyTabsListener` .

```
 public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
           ft.add([id the container /viewgroup in which you have to load your     fragment],fragment)
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not the way to do it, and it seems over complicated...for UI with Tabs, I suggest you to use the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) library, it's well known, reliable and easy to use.